# monitoring multiple streams at once

Tags: java, multithreading, scala, concurrency, stream

I have a collection of a number of Stream[Double].  When I hook up the sockets, and start printing the values from the streams, it works:

```
stream1 foreach println
```

However, if I do this, I only ever get the values from stream1:

```
stream1 foreach println
stream2 foreach println
```

So I wrote one of these :

```
  def monitorStream(label:String, stream:Stream[Double]) = {
    val streamMonitor = new Thread(new Runnable {
      def run() {
        stream foreach {x => println(label,x)}
      }
    })
    streamMonitor.start
  }
```

but in calling

```
monitorStream(label1,stream1)
monitorStream(label2,stream2)
```

I still only get the output for stream1.  How do I monitor the output for these streams simultaneously?

Thanks

Additions:

Defining the streams as follows works:

```
val stream1 = Stream.from(1).map(_.toDouble)
val stream2 = stream1.filter(_ % 5 == 0)
```

but not my actual streams, which produce one double per second apiece.  Further,

```
stream1.zip(stream2) foreach println
```

prints *nothing* (my actual streams here), which makes me suspect this has something to do with the sockets.

Comment: How do you feel about using `zip`? Meaning: `(stream1 zip stream2) foreach println`

Comment: I've toyed around with ideas using zip, but if I go down that route, I'm going to have to zip up * a lot of stuff *.  I want to see what else is out there, first.  Thanks!

Comment: Well, regarding your method. I slightly changed it to better test it in the REPL and it works for me. http://pastebin.com/g9aNppCw

Comment: Dude -- thanks, put this in an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: I just got to test your provided code and it also works for me. I think there is nothing for me to answer.

Comment: It doesn't work for me?  I was assuming yours worked because you were using a List[Stream] ...

Comment: When I paste this (http://pastebin.com/rVGSj1qZ) into the REPL it works as it should.

Comment: ok, thanks -- when I use your code in my app (and in the REPL), it works. those streams spit out doubles as fast as they can.  my real code connects on sockets and each socket gives me a double once a second.  when i use that code, only the first "monitorStream" statement outputs anything. thoughts?